How do I remove the media player controls from the notifcations box? Ubuntu 23.10
There are media controls in my notifications box that just seem to pick up random garbage and add it to the notifications. I never use it, and want to disable it completely. How can I do so?
This is what I want to disable:

Edit: Accidentally put 22.10 instead of 23.10 as version

I figured it out! The nonsense was coming from Firefox, so I disabled Firefox's MPRIS feature by navigating to about:config and setting media.hardwaremediakeys.enabled to FALSE.
